# Method in Trevor Eyre datepicker in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Which method I must use to change date format from MM/DD/YYYY to DD/MM/YYYY?

I search on the Trevor Eyre page and on this forum and I didn't find answer for my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in vba you can simply use

```
Dim DateStr as String

DateStr=Format(DatetoConvert,"dd/mm/yyyy") '<--- change the last
    'part to whatever delimiter you like
```

on a worksheet you can change the format to whatever you want